# Why the email is not confirm on production (.net postgresql)?

Tags: .net, postgresql, console, production-environment, email-confirmation

I'm working with .net core and PostgreSQL.
in local, my email is confirmed in my Postgres database but on production, it doesn't work except if I open the console on google chrome?
Do you know why?

on firefox, it doesn't work at all.
thanks

```
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string token)
    {
        if (userId == null || token == null)
        {
            return new BadRequestObjectResult("Error confirming email");
        }

        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return new BadRequestObjectResult("Error finding id");
        }

        var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, token);
        return new OkObjectResult(result.Succeeded ? "Email confirmed" : "Error confirming email");
    }
```

Comment: You will need to provide additional information to help answer your question. For example, what console messages are in Chrome that are not in FireFox. What is the structure of your URL. Is your production web server accidentally connection to development? With just the above sample code, it is tough to answer correctly.

Comment: There is a URL limit, which is around 4,000 total characters. You may also have issue with URL encoding, if you have any non-alphabetical characters in the query string which would prevent an exact match from your database.